# Lowercase the first letter of the first word of each sentence in a paragraph

Tags: python, string

How to lowercase the first letter of the first word of each sentence in a paragraph? Also, nouns in the middle of sentences will remain capitalized.

How can I do that in Python?

For example: "This is a example sentence. Please help me. I don't want this situation. In Berlin we have a great time." to "this is a example sentence. please help me. i don't want this situation. in Berlin we have a great time."

[image]

I tried this one but this is lower only one sentence.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a regex for this:

```
import re

s = "This is a example sentence. Please help me. I don't want this situation. In Berlin we have a great time."

out = re.sub(r'((?:^|\.)\s*\w+)', lambda m: m.group().lower(), s)
```

output: `"this is a example sentence. please help me. i don't want this situation. in Berlin we have a great time."`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v8tlRG/1)

Comment: This is not working in my navigator :(

Comment: @ulmo how is python code dependent on a "*navigator*". What are you doing exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```py
def first_lower(s):
    paragraph = ''
    _sentences = s.split('.') # split sentences from paragraph using .
    for sentence in _sentences:
        if sentence == '':
            continue
        paragraph += sentence[0].lower() + sentence[1:] + '.' # append converted string to paragraph
    
    return paragraph

string = """this is a example sentence. please help me. i don't want this situation. in Berlin we have a great time."""
print(first_lower(string))
```

Output:

> this is a example sentence. please help me. i don't want this situation. in Berlin we have a great time.

Comment: in the code you have written, it only lowercases the first letter of the first word in the first sentence. When you wrote the sentence, you used all lowercase letters. But my sentences start with capital letters